# How do you send a pdf file using bot framework on a Skype channel?

Tags: pdf, botframework, skype

I would like to send a pdf file using bot-framework on a Skype channel. Similar to how this is done on a telegram channel. [Bot Framework: send pdf file on Telegram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43866197/bot-framework-post-pdf-file). I am really struggling to find useful documentation on using the Skype channel with bot-framework. CardAttachments don't work even though they were coming soon two years ago. Like the Telegram example, I have the pdf as a base64 string. I can't use a link as the pdf is generated from the user's inputs.

This is how I send images. I assume it is something similar.

```
        var cardAttachment = new Attachment()
        {
            ContentUrl = "https://my.url/file.png",
            ContentType = "image/png",
            Name = "filename.png",
        };
        var reply = turnContext.Activity.CreateReply();
        reply.Attachments = new List<Attachment>() { cardAttachment };
        reply.Text = "Some useful text to go along with the image.";
        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(reply, cancellationToken);
```

I tried

```
        var values = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        ...
        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
        var response = await Client.PostAsync(@"https://my.url/report.php", content);
        var report = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
        var cardAttachment = new Attachment()
        {
            ContentUrl = "data:application/pdf;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(report),
            ContentType = "application/pdf",
            Name = $"{answers.Name}.pdf",
        };
        var reply = turnContext.Activity.CreateReply();
        reply.Attachments = new List<Attachment>() { cardAttachment };
        reply.Text = $"{answers.Name} here is your report.";
        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(reply, cancellationToken);
```

It seems to be close but quite right.

**Update**: While Skype blocks you from sending PDFs as attachments in any form (links, local file or Base64Strings) **you can send them as links** by simply embedding the link in your text. It looks like you can send links and local files to WebChat. [Sending Bot Reply message with attachment using Bot Framework](http://jsdotnetsupport.blogspot.com/2017/10/sending-bot-reply-message-with.html) has lots of examples of various approaches.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Attach .txt, .pdf or zip file with skype bot using botframework rest-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50963306/attach-txt-pdf-or-zip-file-with-skype-bot-using-botframework-rest-api)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Skype blocks you from sending PDFs as **attachments** in any form (links, local file or Base64Strings) you can send them as **links** by simply embedding the link in your text.

Answer (score 0):

I know as of this time last year, the Skype channel did not support sending PDF attachments to users due to security concerns - you can see more details regarding this problem [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/4047#issuecomment-359482543). I haven't been able to find any recent documentation contrary to that, nor was I able to send a PDF attachment through my test bot to Skype.  I could, hower, send a PDF to the Emulator and WebChat. Unfortunately, I believe sending PDF attachments is still unsupported by the Skype channel.

Here is the sample code I used to send a PDF attachment to the emulator and WebChat:

```
var reply = turnContext.Activity.CreateReply();

// Create an attachment.
var attachment = new Attachment
{
    ContentUrl = "<path_to_file>/<filename>.pdf",
    ContentType = "application/pdf",
    Name = "<filename>.pdf",
};

// Add the attachment to our reply.
reply.Attachments = new List<Attachment>() { attachment };

// Send the activity to the user.
await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(reply, cancellationToken);
```

Sorry I could not have been of more help.

Comment: Please post the code you use to send it to WebChat.

Comment: I just added the code to send a pdf to webchat. Its very similar to the code snippet you had above.